# JavaScript Setting Time Difference through Loop In Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to store values in an Array using a loop in JavaScript. It only works partially for me.

I want to store time in an Array

There will be startTime, endTime and an interval

For example:
If want to get the time from 9:00 to 10:00 with an interval of 15 minutes, it should print

09:00,09:15,09:30,09:45,10:00

but it's printing

09:00,09:15,09:30,09:45,10:00,10:15,10:30,10:45

Second what should I do if I want to get the time difference between 9:30 and 10:30? or 9:45 and 10:45?

Here is my Code:

HTML

`<div id="time"></div>`

JavaScript

```
var array = new Array();
var timeDiff = 15;
var FirstTime = 9;
var endTime = 10;
for (var xh = FirstTime; xh <= endTime; xh++) {
    for (var xm = 0; xm < 60; xm += timeDiff) {
        array.push(("0" + xh).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + xm).slice(-2));
    }
};
$('#time').text(array)
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6EQ6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i have created a jsfiddle example:-

```
var setIntervals = function (start, end, inc) {
    start = start.toString().split(':');
    end = end.toString().split(':');
    inc = parseInt(inc, 10);

    var pad = function (n) { return (n < 10) ? '0' + n.toString() : n; },
        startHr = parseInt(start[0], 10),
        startMin = parseInt(start[1], 10),
        endHr = parseInt(end[0], 10),
        endMin = parseInt(end[1], 10),
        currentHr = startHr,
        currentMin = startMin,
        previous = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin),
        current = '',
        r = [];

    do {
        currentMin += inc;
        if ((currentMin % 60) === 0 || currentMin > 60) {
            currentMin = (currentMin === 60) ? 0 : currentMin - 60;
            currentHr += 1;
        }
        current = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin);
        r.push(previous + ' - ' + current);
        previous = current;
  } while (currentHr !== endHr);

    return r;
};
```

click here to see example:-http://jsfiddle.net/w6EQ6/3/

or if you don't want to print the range then see the below given link:-

http://jsfiddle.net/w6EQ6/6/

fixed the issue:http://jsfiddle.net/w6EQ6/8/

Comment: Really nice Work but time is showing in range. Can we show it like,9:15,9:30,9:45,10:00?

Comment: i have added new jsfiddle link it will return the desired output please check my answer...

Comment: Its not working when u choose time between 9:30 to 10:30

Comment: i fixed that..see my answer.

Comment: please check compare all the results with console.time.i am using pure calculation so it will be faster then using Date..
First link:-http://jsfiddle.net/w6EQ6/10/show/ using calculation
second link:-http://jsfiddle.net/w6EQ6/11/show/ with date object

check both jsfiddles in firefix and see the time in console.and if you want to see the code then remove the show from url.thanks

Comment: Wow That was awesome! Cool Bro

Answer (score 2):

Well , if you need you to make your loop stop in 10:00 here is the code

```
   var array = new Array();
    var timeDiff = 15;
    var end = 10;
    var start = 9;
    for (var xh = start; xh <= end; xh++) {
        for (var xm = 0; xm < 60; xm += timeDiff) {
            array.push(("0" + xh).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + xm).slice(-2));
             if(xh==end)
                break;
        }
    };
```

now if you want to calculate the difference between two dates here is the function

```
    function difference(date1,date2)
    {
        date1 = new Date(0,0,0,parseInt(date1.split(":")[0]),parseInt(date1.split(":")[1]));
        date2 = new Date(0,0,0,parseInt(date2.split(":")[0]),parseInt(date2.split(":")[1]));
        diff = (((date1>date2)?1:-1)*(date1-date2))/(1000*60*60);
        return diff;
    }
```

you can use this function like this

```
var diff = difference(array[0],array[1]); //for example
```

This function returns the difference in hours if you need in minutes or secondes you have to change the diff variable like this

```
// in minutes
diff = (((date1>date2)?1:-1)*(date1-date2))/(1000*60);
            return diff;
// in seconds
diff = (((date1>date2)?1:-1)*(date1-date2))/1000;
            return diff;
```

Here is a <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7v2c/)**</kbd>

Comment: Really nice suggestion brother. But this what i was looking http://jsfiddle.net/w6EQ6/3/

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that works for 9:30 to 10:30 using one of the answers here:

```
function padLeft(value, padding) {
    return String(padding + value).slice(-padding.length);
}

function getTimeInterval(start, end, interval) {
    var result = [];

    var date = new Date();
    date.setHours(start.hour);
    date.setMinutes(start.minute);


    while (!(date.getHours() === end.hour && date.getMinutes() === end.minute + interval)) {
        result.push(padLeft(date.getHours(), '00') + ':' + padLeft(date.getMinutes(), '00'));
        date = new Date(date.getTime() + interval * 60 * 1000);
    }
    return result;


}
console.log(getTimeInterval({
    hour: 9,
    minute: 30
}, {
    hour: 10,
    minute: 30
}, 15));
```

Comment: One Work For You! GREAT

Answer (score 1):

You are looping one extra, below code will solve your problem

```
for (var xh = FirstTime; xh < endTime; xh++) {
    for (var xm = 0; xm < 60; xm += timeDiff) {
        array.push(("0" + xh).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + xm).slice(-2));
    }
};
array.push(("0" + xh).slice(-2)+':' + ("00").slice(-2));
```

and updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w6EQ6/7/)

Comment: Thank you for your help but 10:00 is still missing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your nesting of for loops. What happens in you code is that the inner loop is executed twice. Once while xh=9 and once when xh=10. This is why you are getting more times than you expect.

One fix would be to change

```
xh <= endTime
```

to

```
xh < endTime
```

This would result in every time up to endTime being printed. To make it inclusive, I would add another line to add the endTime to the array.

So your final loop might look like

```
for (var xh = FirstTime; xh < endTime; xh++) {
    for (var xm = 0; xm < 60; xm += timeDiff) {
        array.push(("0" + xh).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + xm).slice(-2));
    }
    array.push(("0" + endTime).slice(-2) + ':' + ("00").slice(-2));
};
```