# Get intervals separated

Tags: javascript, arrays

Everything works as intended, but I am trying to put into an object these intervals by start and end, currently it give me back an array with time: `7:00 - 7:15`, I want start : `7:00`, end : `7:15`.  Here is my current code.

```
  var setIntervals = function (oc, start, end, inc) {
        start = start.toString().split(':');
        end = end.toString().split(':');
        inc = parseInt(inc, 10);

        var pad = function (n) { return (n < 10) ? '0' + n.toString() : n; },
            startHr = parseInt(start[0], 10),
            startMin = parseInt(start[1], 10),
            endHr = parseInt(end[0], 10),
            endMin = parseInt(end[1], 10),
            currentHr = startHr,
            currentMin = startMin,
            previous = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin),
            current = '',
            r = [];

        do {
            currentMin += inc;
            if ((currentMin % 60) === 0 || currentMin > 60) {
                currentMin = (currentMin === 60) ? 0 : currentMin - 60;
                currentHr += 1;
            }
            current = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin);
            r.push(previous + ' - ' + current);
            previous = current;
      } while (currentHr !== endHr);

        return r;
    };
   var timeInterVals=setIntervals("","<?php echo $closed_now ?>","<?php echo $closed_end ?>","15");
```

This code courtesy of [JavaScript Setting Time Difference through Loop In Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939934/javascript-setting-time-difference-through-loop-in-array)

I know I need to return start and end into my setIntervals, but I keep getting syntax issues.

Here is how I am placing into my array currently.

```
for (var i in timeInterVals){

    var timearr = timeInterVals[i];

    allHours.clinic.push({
        "open or closed" : "",
        "time" : timearr
    });
}
```

My thought is I need to iterate to the start and end within the setInterval function.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
r.push(previous + ' - ' + current);
```

Do,

```
r.push({"start":previous, "end":current});
```

Comment: That works!! But strange behavior... it goes end... then start... so 7:15 to 7: 00

Comment: Thats fine, Objects keys can be in any order, that does not makes any difference.

Comment: Its like `{"end":"something", "start":"something"}` is equivalent to `{"start":"something", "end":"something"}`. If it solves your problem please mark it as right answer.

Comment: Yah I fliped them around no problem.

Comment: Quick question, I could easily use jQuery('#time').text(timeInterVals); to see all the time intervals, but now I get [object][object] do I need to add an additional query to the timeIntervals

Comment: Strigify it, `JSON.stringify(timeInterVals)`