# Interval Array not creating

Tags: javascript, intervals

I found this code but when insert anytime between x:15 - x:45 (x being any associated time) I do not get the intervals for those times.

```
var setIntervals = function (start, end, inc, oc) {
    start = start.toString().split(':');
    end = end.toString().split(':');
    inc = parseInt(inc, 10);
    oc = oc;

    var pad = function (n) { return (n < 10) ? '0' + n.toString() : n; },
        startHr = parseInt(start[0], 10),
        startMin = parseInt(start[1], 10),
        endHr = parseInt(end[0], 10),
        endMin = parseInt(end[1], 10),
        currentHr = startHr,
        currentMin = startMin,
        previous = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin),
        current = '',
        r = [];

    do {
        currentMin += inc;
        if ((currentMin % 60) === 0 || currentMin > 60) {
            currentMin = (currentMin === 60) ? 0 : currentMin - 60;
            currentHr += 1;
        }
        current = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin);
        r.push({"end":current, "start":previous, "OpenClosed":oc});
        previous = current;
  } while (currentHr !== endHr);

    return r;
};

var closedTime=setIntervals("<?php echo $close_now ?>","<?php echo $close_end ?>","15", "closed");
var closeArray = [];
closeArray.push(closedTime);
```

Currently I only get the times from 1:30 - 2:00 but not up to 2:30... If I do 2:00 to 3:00 I get all the intervals.

---

https://jsfiddle.net/pbbsoxrz/

Added the issue into jsfiddle

Courteous of [JavaScript Setting Time Difference through Loop In Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939934/javascript-setting-time-difference-through-loop-in-array)

Comment: *I do not get the intervals for those times.* what do you get? What did you expect? How are you actually calling it (in Javascript not in php). What are the actual values being passed to the `setIntervals` function?  Did you step through the function to see what it's doing?

Comment: Ack... Meant to put what I am actually getting in return. Currently I only get the times from 1:30 - 2:00 but not up to 2:30... If I do 2:00 to 3:00 I get all the intervals.

Comment: *Currently I only get the times from 1:30 - 2:00 but not up to 2:30..* when you pass what as an input? `1:15` and `2:45`? Or something else? Because your question said `x:15 - x:45` from which most people would assume `x` is that same number in both instances.

Comment: See edit, I added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `while` condition and add the part for the minutes with logical or.

```
while (currentHr !== endHr || currentMin !== endMin);
```

```js
var setIntervals = function (start, end, inc, oc) {
    start = start.toString().split(':');
    end = end.toString().split(':');
    inc = parseInt(inc, 10);
    oc = oc;

    var pad = function (n) { return (n < 10) ? '0' + n.toString() : n; },
        currentHr = parseInt(start[0], 10),
        currentMin = parseInt(start[1], 10),
        endHr = parseInt(end[0], 10),
        endMin = parseInt(end[1], 10),
        previous = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin),
        current = '',
        r = [];

    do {
        currentMin += inc;
        currentHr += currentMin / 60 | 0;
        currentMin %= 60;
        current = currentHr + ':' + pad(currentMin);
        r.push({ start: previous, end: current, OpenClosed: oc });
        previous = current;
    } while (currentHr !== endHr || currentMin !== endMin); // <----------- change this!

    return r;
};

var closedTime = setIntervals("12:15", "14:45", "15", "closed");
var closeArray = [];
closeArray.push(closedTime);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(closeArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you want:

```
var setIntervals = function(start, end, inc, oc) {
    var date1 = new Date('2015-1-1 ' + start),
        date2 = new Date('2015-1-1 ' + end),
        r = [],
        current,
        previous;

    // Make sure we increment is a positive number so we don't have an infinite loop
    inc = Math.abs(parseInt(inc, 10));

    do {
        previous = ('0' + date1.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date1.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
        date1.setTime(date1.getTime() + inc * 60 * 1000);
        current = ('0' + date1.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + date1.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
        r.push({
            "end": current,
            "start": previous,
            "OpenClosed": oc
        });
    } while (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime());

    return r;
};

var closeArray = [setIntervals("13:30", "14:30", "15", "closed")];
console.log(closeArray);
```

The while condition of your original code causes the loop to end every time the two hours are equal.

This approach simplify things a bit.